# OCMock Testing delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, ocmock

I have following protocol:

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol {
    func someMethod()
}
```

and then some class conforming to that protocol:

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    ...
    func someMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

My question: how to test (I'm testing in Objective-C with OCMock) that e.g. method call written in someMethod() implemented by SomeClass is actually called?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that knowledgeable in Swift, so I cannot give you a completely accurate answer, however, for Obj-C, I do something like this:

```
id mockDelegate = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(CallViewControllerDelegate));
self.cVC.delegate = mockDelegate;
OCMExpect([mockDelegate callOutcomeSuccessful:OCMOCK_ANY]);
OCMVerifyAll(mockDelegate);
```

With this, you set up an expectation for a mock delegate object, on which you can later verify the call to the delegate method.

Comment: I tried it with Objective-C code and it works, but not with code written in Swift, so it must be some limitation with the Swift language... but many thanks for your help!